# C programming 122 = 12 + 34 - 5 - 6 + 78 + 9

Tags: c

Input n. Put + or - betweeen 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to found a expression equal to n
(122 = 12 + 34 - 5 - 6 + 78 + 9 or 146 = 123 + 45 + 67 - 89)

My idea is that we could fill between 2 numbers 3 values: 0 for no blank, 1 for + and 2 for -
for example 1 + 2 + 3456 - 78 + 9 is 11000201. And this is base-3-number
There are 3^8 expressions to test because we have 8 position to fill, each one has 3 ways.
Start for loop, i from 1 to 3^8. Convert each i to base-3-number and and convert each character of i into + - or no blank to calculate if the present expression is equal to n or not. If equal, print out the expression and end the loop...

My problem is that the program give me the wrong answer and I can't find out a bug.
for example I input 145 but it give me 123 + 45 + 67 - 89 (=146)

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    int n, result, a[100],count, i,j, test,temp, checkpoint,num,checkresult=0;
    printf("Input n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for (num=1;num<=6561;num++)
   {

        count=1;
        test = num;
        result = 0;
        checkpoint=0;
        a[0]=1;
        //convert to base 3
        while (test>0)
        {
            a[count]=test%3;
            //printf("%d ",a[count]);
            test = test/3;
            count++;
        }
        count--;
        //put 0 to fill full 8 blank
        while (count<8)
            {
                count++;
                a[count]=0;
                //printf("%d ",a[count]);

            }
        //inverse the sequence to have the right
        for (i=1;i<=count/2;i++)
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[count+1-i];
            a[count+1-i] = temp;
        }


        //calculate the number
        //1 is +, 2 is -, 0 is no blank

        for (i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            if ((a[i]==1) || (a[i]==2))
            {
                if (a[checkpoint]==1)
                    for (j=checkpoint+1;j<=i;j++)
                        result = result + j*pow(10,i-j);
                if (a[checkpoint]==2)
                    for (j=checkpoint+1;j<=i;j++)
                        result = result - j*pow(10,i-j);
                checkpoint=i;
            }
        }
        if (i==9)
        {
            if (a[checkpoint]==1)
                for (j=checkpoint+1;j<=i;j++)
                    result = result + j*pow(10,i-j);
            if (a[checkpoint]==2)
                for (j=checkpoint+1;j<=i;j++)
                    result = result - j*pow(10,i-j);
        }
        //check if the result is correct or not. If correct, print it out and break the loop
        if (result == n)
        {
            checkresult=1;
            for (i=1;i<=8;i++)
            {
                printf("%d",i);
                if (a[i]==1)
                    printf("+");
                if (a[i]==2)
                    printf("-");
            }
            printf("9\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (checkresult==0)
        printf("Can't found...");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are `2*3^8` possibilities, because you can have nothing or a `-` in front of the `1`.

Comment: Off the wall. Am at a total loss to understand where ternary number system might help, since your example input has 9 different values.

Comment: @WeatherVane At each position, there are three possible things you can put, `+`, `-`, or nothing. So each possibility corresponds to a number in a ternary number system.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

Just have to change the result variable's type into double. Because pow statement require a double type variable

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine for me, here is the screenshot for the output:

[Input: n=145 Output: 123-4-56-7+89](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ptme.jpg)